# System.String ToString() error on a database call using c#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm running into a snag with some code of mine. I have a controller in which I calling to retrieve a company list from my database. However, when I test it I get an error stating that states: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `System.String ToString()` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I cannot seem to figure out a way to fix that and it's been suggested that I use a `foreach` loop.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetCompanyList()
{
    using (var ctx = new Risc_Track_beEntities())
    {
        var companies = ctx.tblCodeBrokerComps.Where(comp => comp.BrokerCompStatus == 1);
        var activeBrokerLocs = companies.Select(b => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = b.BrokerCompID.ToString(),
            Text = b.BrokerComp
        });
        return activeBrokerLocs.ToList<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ to SQL doesn't know how to translate `ToString()` into SQL in this case.

The simplest solution is to use `AsEnumerable` to "transfer control" to LINQ to Objects. You can use an initial `Select` to make sure you only pull the relevant fields from the database, then `AsEnumerable` to get an `IEnumerable<T>`, then another `Select` for the final result:

```
var activeBrokerLocs = companies.Select(b => new { b.BrokerCompID,
                                                   b.BrokerComp })
                                .AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(b => new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Value = b.BrokerCompID.ToString(),
                                    Text = b.BrokerComp
                                });
```

Comment: This worked and I repeated it on a similar function call but another error with the names is coming up.

Comment: @mg2004: I suggest you ask a separate, more detailed question then "another error with the names" doesn't really give enough detail...

Answer (score 1):

you can't call `ToString()` as part of a linq to sql call.   The linq to sql statement gets translated to actual sql, and sql doesn't have a ToString() method.

Try making an object that more closely represents the model in sql, and then convert that to the actual object you need afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use *SqlFunctions.StringConvert*. In your case

```
Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)b.BrokerCompID)
```